# How can I get list in VB.NET of all users currently logged in to a windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows, vb.net, user-accounts

I've got an application running a manufacturing process on a Windows 7 computer. The app has some time-sensitive components that sometimes run slow for a second or two. I know there are a lot of background operations happening in the CLR and OS that can cause program delays, but I've also seen the users sometimes log in to their personal accounts to check email, etc., while my app is running. I'm sure their doing this causes some of the slow-downs. IT says they can't block user accounts on individual computers, so I'd like to have my app text me when the system is running slow and users are logged in to their personal accounts, so I can run over there and call them out on it. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just buy a dedicated PC for this application and lock out all users? Sounds like something your IT people need to work out. Anyway, a Google search came up with [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f337e468-6aac-4d58-a9f7-4ef4bab6b6e7/get-list-of-users-of-current-logged-in-system?forum=csharpgeneral). It's C#.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but no non-IT provided computers allowed, and it's not something they will bother with. Corporate rules rule.

Comment: Looks like you can get this from WMI, by querying the Win32_LoggedOnUser class. You can test the WMI query by running this PowerShell command: `(Get-CimInstance Win32_LoggedOnUser).Antecedent` I'm not a VB.NET dev so I'm not the guy to write WMI code in VB.NET, but this might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Function GetActiveUsers() As List(Of String)
    Dim activeusers As New List(Of String)
    Dim userskey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")
    For Each keyname As String In userskey.GetSubKeyNames()
        Using key As RegistryKey = userskey.OpenSubKey(keyname)
            Dim userpath As String = DirectCast(key.GetValue("ProfileImagePath"), String)
            Dim username As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(userpath)
            Dim useractive As Integer = 0
            If key.GetValueNames.Contains("RefCount") Then useractive = DirectCast(key.GetValue("RefCount"), Integer)
            If useractive <> 0 Then activeusers.Add(username)
        End Using
    Next
    Return activeusers
End Function
```

Comment: this will not just give you all logged in user it will give you all active users, including systemprofile and service users. Basicaly yes it gives you all logged in users but also some more.